# In Yii2 : How to create a form in the model class so that i can reuse the same form

Tags: forms, model, yii2

How can i create a form in the model class that can handle the view portion of the form and all the rules. 
I would just like to create the instance of the form in the controller action and echo it out in the view.
The reason i want to do it this way is because i want everything related to a form handled at one place and reuse the same form again and again.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `ContactForm` model in the application templates? It pretty much does what you are asking for, it could be a good place to start.

Comment: Take a look on [Yii2 widgets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-widgets.html) - prepare one and reuse it as much as you need.

Comment: @RaulSauco yes i did take a look at Contact form. I would like to create the form elements in the model itself.
Similar to way it is being handled in zend framework where a form elements are created inside model and just the form instance is echoed out in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I get your meaning right, here is the solution:

Move your form view to a new file. ex"_form.php"
and then in your view code:

```
$this->render('_form',['model'=>$model]);
```

And in the _form.php you may add some code to determine your reuse scenario.